# Accesing the state of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a parent component which contains a function, which when called needs to acces the children´s component state. I dont want to move the whole state to the parent component because i want the children component to be independent. What is the cleanest and most recommended way to achieve this?

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

render() {

return (
    <div>
        <ChildComponent/>
        <SaveButton onClick={this.saveFunction}/>
    </div>
)
}

saveFunction = () => {
    //Here i need to acces the child Component state
}
}
```

My solution so far was that everytime something changed in child component i called a function which was passed from the parent Component. Like this:

```
class ChildrenComponent extends Component {

    state = {
        name: "David",
        age: 19
    }

    render() {

        return (
            //inputs with the inputChange function
        )
    }   

    inputChange = (e) => {
        //Update the state
        //Then pass the state to the parent
        this.props.passStateToParent(this.state)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! you need to tell us a bit more about what you've done so far

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Don't bend React according to your habits, bend your habits according to React. What you define here is not a proper usage of React. If your Child really needs a state then set your logic there. Define this function in Child component and update the state there. If you need to use the Parent, then lift your state there and don't keep a state in the Child component. React has a unidirectional data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to look up some of the React patterns - especially Render Props, as it allows to expose the state and wanted methods of a component - what you want in this situation.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function in parent component and pass it down to child component as prop. This function could return to parent component the state of your child component. See more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access the state of the child component,this can be done  by passing the state to methods of parent component which are passed as props to child component,the following example demonstrate how to do it .

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
      somefunc() {
         //do your action
           }
      render() {
         <ChildComponent parentfunc={this.somefunc}/>   
}
}
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
          super(props)
          this.state = {somedate:'value'}
          this.func = this.func.bind(this)
}
      func() {
       this.props.parentfunc(this.state)
}
      render() {
       <button onClick={this.func}>text</button>
}

}
```

Comment: @HospiCZ Please verify the answer if it helped you.